# Change data format from yyyy/mm/dd - HH:MM:SS to mm/dd/yyyy - HH:MM:SS in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date-format

I need to change the date format of a `string`. The original string is formatted like so:

```
var timeStamp = '2014/07/30 - 14:15:36'
```

and this is the date format I'm tring to achive:

```
var timeStampArranged = '07/30/2014 - 14:15:36'
```

so in other words I need to change `yyyy/mm/dd - HH:MM:SS` to `mm/dd/yyyy - HH:MM:SS`

Comment: can be done with simple string manipulation. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oneliner with Regular Expression and [.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```
var timeStampArranged  = timeStamp.replace(/([0-9]{4})\/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{2})/, "$2/$3/$1");
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use some substring (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp) and concatinate the wanted parts into a new variable.

```
var ts = '2014/07/30 - 14:15:36'

var newTimeStamp = "";
newTimeStamp += ts.substr(5, 2);
newTimeStamp += "/";
newTimeStamp += ts.substr(8, 2);
newTimeStamp += "/";
newTimeStamp += ts.substr(0, 4);
newTimeStamp += " - ";
newTimeStamp += ts.substr(13, 8);

alert(newTimeStamp);
```

Answer (score 1):

As Steini mentions, you can use string manipulation to achieve this.  Another method is to use the fruits of other peoples' labour: [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/).

```
moment(timestamp, "YYYY/MM/DD - HH:mm:ss").format("MM/DD/YYYY - HH:mm:ss");
```

Seems like a bit much to load another lib if you only need it for this one scenario, but the code is far more readable.